# error Cannot read property 'setParams' of undefined - lightning component

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components

In a lightning component I call an apex method, like that :

```
for(var cmp in component.find("inQuantity")){
  var CallMethod = component.get("c.calculate")[cmp]; 
  var product = component.get("v.product")[cmp];
  CallMethod.setParams({
    "prod" : JSON.stringify(product)
  });
  vCalcMethod.setCallback(pComponent, function(pResponse) {
    //some code
  });
  $A.enqueueAction(CallMethod);
}
```

The apex method need a string in parameter, I try to pass it through the `setParams`. But at this point I got an error in javascript :

> Cannot read property 'setParams' of undefined

But when I put a debug `console.log('product to string' + JSON.stringify(product ));` I got the object into a string, like I want, it is not "undefined".

Comment: Here it's your CallMethod variable that is undefined, not product.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `CallMethod` variable is undefined. Try changing:

`var CallMethod = component.get("c.calculate")[cmp];`

to

`var CallMethod = component.get("c.calculate");`

and make sure you've defined an action called `calculate` that's accessible on your `component`.